# How to Override Meteor Core Packages in a Project?

Tags: javascript, git, meteor, meteor-packages

For a Meteor project I want to make changes to a Meteor Core library file.

Is this possible and if so, how?

So far I've tried just copying the files into my project directory hoping that the respective Objects are just overwritten from the originals but the problem herewith was that dependent functions or variables were only defined locally.

Then I tried to `git clone` them into the project's `packages` directory like you would do with a community package, but that didn't function either since the clone command failed (`fatal: repository ... not found`) and also the package is not explicitly called in the .meteor/packages file.

Any idea?

Comment: What command did you use to clone the packages? What error did you get?

Comment: @MasterAM:
git clone https://github.com/meteor/meteor/commit/025299f28606426aeb54628740108ad162503ce4

Cloning into '025299f28606426aeb54628740108ad162503ce4'...

fatal: repository 'https://github.com/meteor/meteor/commit/025299f28606426aeb54628740108ad162503ce4/' not found

and another try:

git clone https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/devel/packages/ddp-client

Cloning into 'ddp-client'...

fatal: repository 'https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/devel/packages/ddp-client/' not found

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Meteor allows having local packages in a project, including ones that override existing (community or core) packages.

While overriding a community package locally often simply requires cloning (or extracting or adding as submodule) the GitHub repository into the `/packages` folder, core packages currently live inside sub-directories of the main `meteor/meteor` repository, which makes cloning them trickier.

Overriding a core package may require you to manually apply changes to the package as Meteor or the package update (as Meteor used to be dependent on specific package versions).

Therefore, before taking such step, **make sure that you actually need to do it**.

Make sure that you cannot you make your changes using local files or your own local package (e.g, by wrapping or replacing a function or monkey-patching it).

There are a few approaches that I used in order to override a core package.

### Clone the entire repository and link the directories

This is useful if you want to contribute your changes to the project. You should probably fork the repository and clone your own fork.

1. Clone the meteor repository:

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/meteor/meteor.git
   ```

   or

   `git clone git@github.com:<username>/meteor.git` if you forked it
2. Link the package directory (in your project's `packages` directory)

   ```
   ln -s ../../(...)/meteor/packages/
   ```

   You can checkout the desired branch/commit and copy them to the local `packages` directory instead, of course.

### Statically download only the package directory

There is a neat trick that allows you to download a given directory from GitHub using `svn`.

This is obtained by issuing:

```
svn export https://github.com/meteor/meteor/[trunk|branches/]/packages/
```

for example:

cloning `ddp-client` from the `devel` branch:

```
svn export https://github.com/meteor/meteor/branches/devel/packages/ddp-client
```

or from the `master` branch:

```
svn export https://github.com/meteor/meteor/trunk/packages/ddp-client
```

---

Notes:

1. As mentioned earlier, you may need to manually apply changes if you update Meteor.
2. Don't forget to add the package to the project (`meteor add <package>`) if you haven't already.
3. Meteor is expected to switch to NPM at some point (possibly in Meteor v1.5), so make sure to use the methods specified in this answer only for meteor's own packaging system.

Comment: Hi there,

it actually works, with method 1 and then soft linking the package and adding it with `meteor add ddp-client`

Comment: Indeed, but it has a lot of overhead. Use with care.